# Predict binary outcome with longitudinal data

Tags: predictive-models, panel-data, binary-data

I have a dataset with experiments. Each of them was performed with different settings. The outcome, binary, is only known once the experiment is over after 60 minutes. We collect data every 30 seconds, so we have 120 observations per experiment, and one single outcome for the whole. It looks something like (shortened data):

| Experiment | Time | Force | Weight | Speed | Bright | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 10 | 220 | 3 | 10 | Yes |
| 1 | 1 | 12 | 230 | 4 | 11 | Yes |
| 1 | 1.5 | 15 | 239 | 6 | 12 | Yes |
| 2 | 0.5 | 11 | 200 | 1 | 13 | No |
| 2 | 1 | 13 | 210 | 2 | 16 | No |
| 2 | 1.5 | 17 | 250 | 4 | 19 | No |
| 3 | 0.5 | 5 | 320 | 7 | 20 | Yes |
| 3 | 1 | 6 | 326 | 8 | 21 | Yes |
| 4 | 1.5 | 7 | 335 | 10 | 24 | Yes |

Frequently the different variables are increasing/decreasing in value over time as the experiment advances in time. The problem here is that the variable outcome would be for the whole experiment and not for one single row. My objective is to predict this outcome by looking at the data of the experiment over time. The issue I am having here is to develop a ML, potentially tree-based method, that can predict this outcome by using the relevant information but taking into account inter-experiment information. This issue also arises when planning a CV method. I'd appreciate some inputs.